# Change the registered class in autofac DI during tests with specflow

Tags: c#, mocking, integration-testing, specflow

Im using specflow with autofac and register the container using

```cs
[ScenarioDependencies]
public static ContainerBuilder CreateContainerBuilder()
{
    var autofacBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    autofacBuilder.RegisterTypes(typeof(Setup).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(BindingAttribute))).ToArray()).SingleInstance();
    return autofacBuilder;
}
```

then in the tests i would like to do something along the line of

```cs
[Given(@"Set mock class")]
public void SetMockClass()
{
    var autofacBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    autofacBuilder.RegisterType<TestMock>().As<IRealClass>().SingleInstance();
    var fakeContainer = autofacBuilder.build();
    fakeContainer.Update(realContainer);
}
```

the mock is dependent on the test so i cant do it in the setup,
How can i do this in my tests ?

Comment: Short answer - in 99.99% of cases your unit tests should _not_ interact with Autofac. Instead you should new up the class you are testing directly, and pass any mocks / stubs to its constructor.

Comment: in the case of unit test you are right, i will create instance of the tested class mock all injected classes and test it
on the case of integration test im testing full flow and any external connection is mocked, in this case i would like to change the mocks dependent on the test